How to deploy Strapi project with mysql database on hostinger?
I was working on a project where i have used strapi headless cms for the backend, used mysql as the database. Now i am looking forward to deploy it on hostinger. but i have not found any way there in online. Can anyone guide me on this that how to deploy this project?
